# Complex Dictionary Print

Tags: c#, dictionary

I created a complex dictionary.

```
mainDict<mainKey, SubDict>
subDict<subKey, sub1Dict>
sub1Dict<sub1Key, sub2Dict>
sub2Dict<sub2Key, sub2Value>
.......
```

How to print it out like this (vs2005 & .net 2.0 based)

```
mainKey/subKey/sub1Key/sub2Key, sub2Value
```

Do i need convert mainDict to a List and call join()?

thank you.

Comment: Hi, imho good idea to reveal fundamental types and class scope modifiers (static, etc.) you are using "up front" in your original question in a very strange and complex example like this : only in your 2nd. comment to Darin's answer below do you finally tell us that 'mainDict is : "static dictionary<string, object>." We know nothing about the Types of the various sub-keys, sub-dictionaries, or the sub2Value type : we don't know if sub2Dict is sub-classed from sub1Dict, etc. My "psychic" powers are dim :)

Comment: Okay. I also agree that my original post is not clear. you guys already helped me a lot. I benefited from your replies. - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<mainKey, SubDict> pair1 in mainDict)
foreach (KeyValuePair<subKey, sub1Dict> pair2 in pair1.Value)
foreach (KeyValuePair<sub1Key, sub2Dict> pair3 in pair2.Value)
foreach (KeyValuePair<sub2Key, sub2Value> pair4 in pair3.Value)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}, {4}", 
        pair1.Key, pair2.Key, pair3.Key, pair4.Key, pair4.Value);
}
```

---

UPDATE:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair1 in mainDict)
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair2 in (Dictionary<string, object>)pair1.Value)
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair3 in (Dictionary<string, object>)pair2.Value)
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair4 in (Dictionary<string, object>)pair3.Value)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}, {4}", 
        pair1.Key, pair2.Key, pair3.Key, pair4.Key, pair4.Value);
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin, Acturally, mainDict generated from a parsing result of XSD file. There is no keyword can be inserted to my code. i declared mainDict as a static dictionary<string, object> . I am afraid i can't foreach (KeyWord Content) as your suggestion. how to extend the StringBuilder loop method to meet my requirement? thank you.

Comment: sb.AppendFormat("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}, {4}", - Can't using the fixed 4 variables. The items number will changed dynamical based on the mainDic layers. This means the mainDict generated dynamical and if the XSD file change, the mainDic must changed too. and the top code still could hande the dynamical condition.

Answer (score 2):

Can't see anything much better than nested loops for this - iterate over mainDict's keys, then subDict's keys inside that, and so on. You can then render the loop variables and the innermost value as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ:

```
var qry = from pair1 in mainDict
          from pair2 in pair1.Value
          from pair3 in pair2.Value
          from pair4 in pair3.Value
          select pair1.Key + "/" + pair2.Key + "/" + pair3.Key
                   + "/" + pair4.Key + ", " + pair4.Value;

foreach(var s in qry) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Hi Marc, vs2005 & .net 2.0 used in my project. I am afraid i can't use LINQ tech.

Comment: For info, if you had VS2008 you can still use LINQ-to-Objects with .NET 2.0 via LINQBridge: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing one after trying a few minutes to find one here. Here we go:

```
        //---------------------------------------------------
        // Get a nested Dictionary, then...
        Console.WriteLine(DictionaryPrint(nestedDictionary));
        //---------------------------------------------------

        private static string DictionaryPrint(Dictionary<object,object> dictionary, string space = "")
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach(KeyValuePair<object,object> entry in dictionary)
            {
                output += space + entry.Key + ": ";
                if (entry.Value is Dictionary<object, object>)
                    output += "\n" + DictionaryPrint((Dictionary<object, object>)entry.Value, space + "  ");
                else if (entry.Value is List<object>)
                    output += "\n" + ListPrint((List<object>)entry.Value, space + "  ");
                else
                    output += entry.Value + "\n";
            }
            return output;
        }

        private static string ListPrint(List<object> list, string space = "")
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (object entry in list)
            {
                if (entry is List<object>)
                    output += ListPrint((List<object>)entry, space + "  ");
                else if (entry is Dictionary<object, object>)
                    output += DictionaryPrint((Dictionary<object, object>)entry, space + "  ");
                else
                    output += entry + "\n";
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using JSON, you could do worse than

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDict, Formatting.Indented);
```